# Android / XML - Unable to Display 2nd Carousel

Tags: android, xml

I'm attempting to display 2 carousels - and I am able to successfully display one but the 2nd one is missing. I believe this has to do with an issue with my 2nd HorizontalScrollView in the XML. I am not sure what I have done wrong. Suggestions are appreciated. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvXl3.jpg
Any additional information requested will be provided promptly.

### Source:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

  <!--  1st Child Layout  (Nested In Parent Layout) with Horizontal Orientation -->

    <LinearLayout 
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:background="#000000"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:hint="Search Movies"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"


            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:text="Reset" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"

            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Sort by:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

   </LinearLayout>

    <!--  2nd Child Layout  (Nested In Parent Layout) with Horizontal Orientation -->
   <LinearLayout 
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- Container view to scroll horizontally which gives the carousel effect -->
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:scrollbars="none">

        <!-- Carousel items container - lays out items horizontally -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/carousel"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"/>


    </HorizontalScrollView>

        <!-- Container view to scroll horizontally which gives the carousel effect -->
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                          android:scrollbars="none">

        <!-- Carousel items container - lays out items horizontally -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/carousel2"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"/>


    </HorizontalScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>

  <!--  3rd Child Layout  (Nested In Parent Layout) with Horizontal Orientation -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
         <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:textColor="#505050"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp"
              android:text="@string/KNewArrivals" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1a"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel " />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In the image you added, I'm assuming that all the movie icons are part of one horizontal scroll view?  Is it your goal to have two scrollers side by side?

Comment: I want two horizontal scroll views - one below the other. I'm unsure why I got a downvote on this question... any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your horizontal scroll views are set to be side by side, and both have the match_parent attribute.  The second one is pushed off the screen by the first.

Either set the linear layout to vertical to have the horizontal layouts on on top of the other, or set the horizontal scroll views to width 0dp with a layout weight.